# Vector Drawables Using Lots of Memory

Tags: android, drawable, android-vectordrawable

So I have 11 different drawables that I have made into vectors, I have used them as images for all devices that are on versions later than lollipop and it works ok as images but the vectors either make it extremely laggy or they make the app crash due to not having enough memory.

I thought vectors would be more efficient than images.

Here's an example of my vector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="612dp"
    android:height="792dp"
    android:viewportWidth="612"
    android:viewportHeight="792">

<path
    android:fillColor="#C03A2B"
    android:pathData="M 306 90 C 474.999133448 90 612 227.000866552 612 396 C 612 564.999133448 474.999133448 702 306 702 C 137.000866552 702 0 564.999133448 0 396 C 0 227.000866552 137.000866552 90 306 90 Z" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M483.9,584.7L301.1,415.4c-10.9-10.2-15.5-23.7-9.7-29.5l5.6-5.6c5.9-5.9,19.5-1.3,29.5,9.7l169.5,182.6
    c2.2,2.4,1.8,6.3-0.7,9l-2.5,2.5C490.2,586.5,486.1,587,483.9,584.7z" />
</vector>
```

I'm displaying these in a gridView which randomly sets them as the image resource for imageviews that are created.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you'll have problems due to the size of those drawables, see [this guidance](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html#about) which includes:

> The initial loading of a vector graphic can cost more CPU cycles than the corresponding raster image. Afterward, memory use and performance are similar between the two. We recommend that you limit a vector image to a maximum of 200 x 200 dp; otherwise, it can take too long to draw.

Comment: They end up getting drawn relative to the screen width so that size doesn't matter too much. I thought due to the smaller file size vectors would use less memory but didn't realise the computational overhead would be so great.

Comment: I think I will just use heavily compressed images, was a good lesson learnt any way.

Comment: Does viewportHeight and viewportWidth also affect memory usage i.e. is it also recommended to set them to a maximum of 200 x 200 dp ?